# Trigger action jobs from submodule

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I need to trigger a github action when a submodule repository is updated.
I am building a multi module maven application with multiple dependent projects and a parent project.

When the subprojects are pushed to, the parent one needs to trigger the action. If possible i would like to choose what jobs is executed to limit full rebuild of the project each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `push` events to your submodules you can create a [`repository_dispatch`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) event for the parent repository. Configure the payload to include which submodule has been updated and that will allow you to limit what gets rebuilt.

```
      - name: Repository Dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          repository: username/parent-repo
          event-type: build-project
          client-payload: '{"submodule": "${{ github.repository }}"}'
```

See [repository-dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/repository-dispatch) for further details and examples.