# GitHub Scheduled action pushes submodule change but push triggered action does not run

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

## Overview

I have a private 'parent' github repository with two workflows and a submodule. It has one branch called main.

## First parent workflow

One workflow is triggered when there is a push to the parent repository. This works when I push a file change to repository. (But not when the other workflow pushes a submodule reference change to the parent.)

```
# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "main" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
```

## Second parent workflow

A second workflow is scheduled/manually. This brings the submodule up to date on it's branch and then push the submodule reference change, if there is one, to the parent repository. This works and I can see the commit in the parent repository when it does this.

## Summary

So is see the scheduled workflow run in the parent repository. I see the commit to the paren repository and the commit changes the submodule reference. When browsing the main branch of the parent repository in GitHub I can see the commit and can navigate to the new submodule reference. But the first parent workflow has not run. However, pushing a change to a file in the parent repository does trigger the first workflow to run. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger action jobs from submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378595/trigger-action-jobs-from-submodule)

Comment: @GuiFalourd this is a great solution. However I wanted to keep the submodule as it is and there for only add workflow related things to the parent. It would be great to understand the limitation I am seeing.